# Is there a way for the user to type in a value on a tkinter combobox, and add the value to the dropdown?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, dropdown

So I'm basically trying to make a Combobox where the user can enter some text in the textbox, clicks a button, and then the text they entered is automatically added to the dropdown list of the combobox. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Here is some rough code I have so far:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Forklift calling EOL interface")
root.resizable(True, True)
root.attributes('-fullscreen', False)

# Create a frame
frame = tk.Frame(root, background=app_background)
frame.grid()
root.anchor("center")


main_title = tk.Label(frame, text = "Title",font=("Helvetica", 30))
subtitle = tk.Label(frame, text = "Subtitle",font=("Helvetica", 15) )
var = tk.IntVar()
part_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=var, values=empty, font=("Helvetica", 20), width=24, background=button_background, state="readonly")
send_item = tk.Button(frame, text ="->")
add_item = tk.Button(frame, text ="+",command = new_item)

#Putting the stuff in the grid 
main_title.grid(row=0, column=0,pady=10, padx= (0,0))
subtitle.grid(row=1, column = 0, pady = 6, padx=(0,0) )
send_item.grid(row=2, column = 0, pady = 6, padx= (25,0))
add_item.grid(row=3, padx= (30,0))
part_dropdown.grid(row=2, column = 0, pady = 6)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cget` method to get the current value and the contents of the `values` attribute, append the new value to the values, and then use `configure` to set the new list of values.

Here's a working example. To trigger the function in this example, enter something and press return.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def update_combobox(event):
    new_value = event.widget.get()
    values = list(event.widget.cget("values")) or []
    if new_value not in values:
        values.append(new_value)
        event.widget.configure(values=values)

root = tk.Tk()
dropdown = ttk.Combobox(root, width=24)
dropdown.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

dropdown.bind("<Return>", update_combobox)

tk.mainloop()
```

If you want to call this from a function, just remove the `event` parameter and directly access the combobox via a global variable (or instance variable if you use classes). The basic concept is still the same: get the value, the the list of values, append the value to the list, and update the combobox.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def update_combobox():
    new_value = dropdown.get()
    values = list(dropdown.cget("values")) or []
    if new_value not in values:
        values.append(new_value)
        dropdown.configure(values=values)

root = tk.Tk()
dropdown = ttk.Combobox(root, width=24)
button = tk.Button(root, text="Update the combobox", command=update_combobox)
button.pack(side="bottom")
dropdown.pack(side="top", padx=10, pady=10)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What change can I make such that the value updates when clicking a button rather than clicking "Enter"? I'm guessing I'll have to make a change to the           
 "<Return>" right?

Comment: @dqdqdqsss: I've updated the answer to show how to use a function.